# One application code with multiple contextpaths/deployments to connect to different databases

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins, websphere, cloud-foundry

Encountered a requirement in our team when trying to migrate a WebSphere application into Tomcat and deploy onto Pivotal Cloud Foundry to have same application to connect to two different databases which have entirely same schema with different data, essentially having same application code deployed in different paths and be able to connect to the databases based on the URL being called for accessing the application.

Currently, we handle this situation in Websphere by using the deployment script  to deploying the application into two servers and give the different database details in JNDI and access the application using the server names.

We use Jenkins to deploy the application onto PCF.

Tried to use maven to deploy on to different context paths which did not help and have ended up in the loop,  Have anyone encountered a situation like this, Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a number of ways you could handle this.

1. Modify your application so it's aware and let's you pick. Perhaps have a query parameter to select or `/dev/blah` goes to one DB and `/test/blah` goes to another.
2. Push the same application twice, but bind different databases and routes to each app.
3. Attempt to run two instances of the same app code inside Tomcat in one app on CF.

Of those, #1 is fine but would probably require code changes. #2 would be my choice as it's very quick to do, #3 would be a lot of work because you'd be fighting against the Java buildpack, which is not recommended.

---

To accomplish #2, you would do the following:

1. Push your app code as app-A.
2. Bind the database service.
3. Map a route with a context path like `my-cool-app.example.com/app-a`.
4. Start your app.

Repeat the same for app-B, but use a different database and route/path (i.e. my-cool-app.example.com/app-b)`.

If you are deploying a WAR file, you will need to tell the Java buildpack to deploy your app on a context path (it should match the route context path you set).

```
cf set-env my-application JBP_CONFIG_TOMCAT '{tomcat: { context_path: /app-a }}'
```

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/container-tomcat.md#common-configurations

If you're using Spring Boot and a JAR deployment, you'd need to set `server.contextPath=/app-a`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, the answer helped!